# Trying to change the password and getting error indicating password is expired

Tags: linux

Using Linux release -- Linux 2.6.16.60

Trying to change password on a account using root and getting the following error -

```
XX:/home/service # passwd admin

 Changing password for admin.

 passwd: User account has expired
```

How does one go about changing the password or resetting the password for an account. I have access to the root account for the system.

Answer (score 2):

Um, the account has expired, not the password.

You need to use usermod to unexpire the password.

I think the syntax is:

```
usermod -e [date] <username>
```

So,

```
usermod -e 2525/12/31 philipjfry
```

Would set the expiration date of my "phillipjfry" user to December 31st in the year 2525.  Of course, he'd still be waiting for his backwards time machine at that point, but that's a different problem.

Not sure about the exact format of the date flag (pretty sure different distros do it differently), but that should be what you're looking for.  Consult your distro's man page on usermod for exact formatting.  Might wanna check out some [Linux documentation](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Shadow-Password-HOWTO-7.html) sties while you're at it, too...

Answer (score 0):

Get into a console connection (SUSE VM's), log into the machine locally as root, reset the password with YaST then change it again on the CLI as normal.

I had this same problem yesterday on my SUSE Servers that I let the password expire by accident. None of these commands worked for me but that seemed to work well enough.